# How to enable/disable parameters(automatically) based on another parameter? VS 2005

Tags: checkbox, reporting-services, visual-studio-2005, bids

I am not sure if this is doable in SSRS 2005 but I have below mentioned scenario and need your help.

I have three parameters "p1", "p2" and "p3" and three of them have a default null value.

Now.. If I uncheck null from @p1 parameter, I want the p2 and p3 parameter to have the default NULL value checked and if @p1 parameter is set to null meaning if the NULL checkbox for p1 is checked, I want the p2 and p3 parameters to uncheck.

I tried to set the default value via the expression (iif..)  and I also create a separate dataset to set the default values but I received an error stating that "forward dependencies are not valid"

I am using VS2005. Please help. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Which expressions have you tried? It might be helpful to include them in the question.

Comment: @Tino Thanks for your reply. I tried using iif

Comment: I'll need a little bit more than just IIf... Can you provide the full expression(s)?